# Utilizar dois campos com definições diferentes no Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper

Estou com uma dificuldade:
Estou tentando utilizar um campo que foi criado como **number** com um campo criado como `NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE`.

#### O campo ID_ACESSO foi criado assim:

```
"ID_ACESSO" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE
```

#### O campo PK_ACESSO foi criado assim:

```
"PK_ACESSO" NUMBER,
```

```
 select * from gsc_tbl066_ramal_telefonico a 
           left join gsc_view_tbl064_acesso b 
                on a.PK_ACESSO = b.ID_ACESSO;
```

Quando executo dá o erro:

> ORA-01722: número inválido
> 01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
> *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
> *Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: o problema deve ser conta de valores null no campo "ID_ACESSO", tente acrescentar um `WHERE b.ID_ACESSO IS NOT NULL` ao final da query

Comment: ainda dá o mesmo erro :(

Comment: A tabela tem colunas virtuais ? Tem certeza dos types ? A sql é exatanente esta ?